# My internal linearLayout have some margin at bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

my Internal Linear Layout (with blue background) seems to have some margin at bottom with white space, do not know how to remove this.
The External Linear layout also have no padding or margin , from where this whitespace came

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#E78F23">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:onClick="dashboard"
                android:src="@drawable/menu"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ticket_reciever_header_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Mike Smith"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#20000000"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="35%0FF"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textColor="@color/background_material_dark"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/layer"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#91A4AB"
            android:weightSum="3">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_height="55dp">
                          <TextView
                              android:id="@+id/product_name"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                              android:text="AMG 020 ladies shirt"
                              android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                              android:textSize="20sp"
                              />
                                <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@id/product_name"
                                android:text="Purple heather"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"

                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                />
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/share_upper"/>

                </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/qr_code"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

        <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"

                        android:layout_gravity="center"

                        android:background="#3E41B2"

                        >
                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/shedule"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@drawable/tecket_recieved_shedule"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="#00000000"/>
                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/location"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/ticket_received_location"
                            android:background="#00000000"/>
                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/favourite"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@drawable/favourite"
                            android:layout_weight="1"

                            android:background="#00000000"/>
                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@drawable/share"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="#00000000"/>

                    </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etU9o.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etU9o.jpg)

Comment: change android:layout_height="50dp" to android:layout_height="match
_parent" in your last linear layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

in your last LinearLayout.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just update your last Linear Layout Height . Set **`match_parent`** instead `Hard-Coded 50dp` .

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#3E41B2"

                    >
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/shedule"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/tecket_recieved_shedule"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#00000000"/>
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/location"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/ticket_received_location"
                        android:background="#00000000"/>
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/favourite"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/favourite"
                        android:layout_weight="1"

                        android:background="#00000000"/>
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/share"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#00000000"/>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the height of the layout as a fixed value (50dp). Change it so it takes all available space changing

```
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

for

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

For future ui issues like this you can enable "Show layout bounds" in Developer Options. It will show the size of every view in the screen